Discretization of Schrödinger equation using Crank-Nicolson method
I'm trying to show that discretizing the Schrödinger equation $i\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = - \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}} - \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}} + v(x, y)u$ according to the Crank-Nicolson approach is
$$u^{n+1}_{ij} -r[u_{i+1,j}^{n+1} - 2u_{i,j}^{n+1} + u_{i-1,j}^{n+1}] -r [u_{i,j+1}^{n+1} - 2u_{i,j}^{n+1} + u_{i,j-1}^{n+1}] + \frac{i\Delta t}{2}v_{i,j}u_{i,j}^{n+1} = u^{n}_{ij} + r[u_{i+1,j}^{n} - 2u_{i,j}^{n} + u_{i-1,j}^{n}] + r[u_{i,j+1}^{n} - 2u_{i,j}^{n} + u_{i,j-1}^{n}] - \frac{i\Delta t}{2}v_{i,j}u_{i,j}^{n}$$
where $r \equiv \frac{i\Delta t}{2h^{2}}$
From what I have already tried, I have the expression
$$i\frac{u^{n+1}_{ij} - u^{n}_{ij}}{\Delta t} = \frac{1}{2}(-\frac{u_{i+1,j}^{n+1} - 2u_{i,j}^{n+1} + u_{i-1,j}^{n+1}}{h^{2}} - \frac{u_{i,j+1}^{n+1} - 2u_{i,j}^{n+1} + u_{i,j-1}^{n+1}}{h^{2}} + v_{i,j}u_{i,j}^{n+1}) + \frac{1}{2}(-\frac{u_{i+1,j}^{n} - 2u_{i,j}^{n} + u_{i-1,j}^{n}}{h^{2}} - \frac{u_{i,j+1}^{n} - 2u_{i,j}^{n} + u_{i,j-1}^{n}}{h^{2}} + v_{i,j}u_{i,j}^{n})$$
My question is, how do I get $i$ in every term of the expression except for $u^{n+1}_{ij}$ and $u^{n}_{ij}$? If I just rearrange the expression to the structure of the expression in the problem, $i$ is not in any term BUT $u^{n+1}_{ij}$ and $u^{n}_{ij}$. Like this:
$$iu^{n+1}_{ij} - \frac{\Delta t}{2h^{2}}(u_{i+1,j}^{n+1} - 2u_{i,j}^{n+1} + u_{i-1,j}^{n+1}) - \frac{\Delta t}{2h^{2}}(u_{i,j+1}^{n+1} - 2u_{i,j}^{n+1} + u_{i,j-1}^{n+1}) + \frac{\Delta t}{2}v_{i,j}u_{i,j}^{n+1} = iu^{n}_{ij} + \frac{\Delta t}{2h^{2}}(u_{i+1,j}^{n} - 2u_{i,j}^{n} + u_{i-1,j}^{n}) + \frac{\Delta t}{2h^{2}}(u_{i,j+1}^{n} - 2u_{i,j}^{n} + u_{i,j-1}^{n}) - \frac{\Delta t}{2}v_{i,j}u_{i,j}^{n}$$

Multiply all the terms of your last equation by $i$, and replace $\frac{i\Delta t}{2h^2}$ with $r$.

Using $i$ as both an index and $\sqrt{-1}$ seems liable to generate mistakes.
